# How to properly handle space before a redefined \subsection?

Tags: vertical-spacing, subsection

I am trying to define a new subsection command in which the entire line with the header is colored and in which I can provide an extra input *after* the subsection title, but on the same line as the title. My problem is that I do not handle the vertical spacing before the subtitle properly. If the subtitle follows an ordinary paragraph, I want to add space, but if the subtitle comes after a page break, no extra space should be added.

An example is given as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\definecolor{LightGrey}{gray}{.85}
\definecolor{Red}{rgb}{0.8,0.05,0.05}
\definecolor{Green}{rgb}{0.22,0.7,0.0}

\newcommand{\trafficlight}[2]{\textcolor{#1}{\begin{picture}(#2,#2)(0,0)\put(0,3.5){\circle*{#2}}\end{picture}}}

\lhead{}
\rhead{\begin{tabular}{r}\cr\nouppercase{\small\leftmark}\end{tabular}}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\small\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\mysubsection}[2]{
\ \\[1.5\baselineskip]
%\ \vspace{1.5\baselineskip}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{.97\textwidth}}
\cellcolor{LightGrey}
{
\begin{tabularx}{.95\textwidth}{m{.82\textwidth}R{.1\textwidth}}
{\hspace*{-3.5ex}
\refstepcounter{subsection}
\normalfont\large\bfseries\thesubsection{}\hspace*{2.5ex}{#1}}
&
{
\trafficlight{#2}{10} 
}
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{tabularx}
% Manually add the section to toc-file
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}
%
\\
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
Yada yada.
\subsection{Normal subsection}
Yada yada.
\mysubsection{My subsection}{Green}
Yada yada.
\newpage
\mysubsection{This is not at the top of the page}{Red}
Yada yada.
\end{document}
```

This is my output:

[image: First page]
[image: Second page]

Comment: Why don't you do that with the dedicated package – `titlesec`? It has a `\titleformat` and a `\titlespacing`  commands.

Comment: I tried but failed. How would you approach it? (Please note that I want to keep the possibility of using the ordinary subtitles in my document as well.)

Comment: If your problem is the vertical spacing  of the subtitle, I think it should be managed in the last (optional) argument of `\titleformat`,

Comment: I don't see how to give an extra input to the \subsection command by means of \titleformat. My new command takes two separate arguments: the subtitle and the color used at the right end of the subtitle line.

Comment: I don't understand your screenshot, which is a screenshot of the table of contents. Is it the latter you want to modify or the subsection itself?

Comment: sectioning comands have their own space controls that you should use but never add vertical space like `\ \\[1.5\baselineskip]` that is not vertical space that is a paragraph of text that just consists of a spac but as its a line of text it is not dropped at a page break. You have a vertical space commented out that would be better,

Comment: also beware spaces from ends of lines `\newcommand{\mysubsection}[2]{` etc are all adding space tokens use `%` to comment out the end of line.

Comment: @David Carlisle 
I tried the vertical space, but then my new subsection does not start on a new line, but starts on the same line as the proceeding paragraph.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the space tokens from `\newcommand`.

Comment: @Bernard I want to get rid of the leading vertical space before the subsection on the second page.

Comment: you need `\par` before a vertical space to get into vertical mode, but you should be using the standard latex section heading definition constructs not spacing by hand like this, you are breaking all the standard control over page breaking around sections. the `\\ ` at the end is similarly wrong. I can not run your example it produces `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.`

Comment: It might have been the `[table]` option in `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` caused the option clash. I removed that in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\definecolor{LightGrey}{gray}{.85}
\definecolor{Red}{rgb}{0.8,0.05,0.05}
\definecolor{Green}{rgb}{0.22,0.7,0.0}

\newcommand{\trafficlight}[2]{\textcolor{#1}{\begin{picture}(#2,#2)(0,0)\put(0,3.5){\circle*{#2}}\end{picture}}}

\lhead{}
\rhead{\begin{tabular}{r}\nouppercase{\small\leftmark}\end{tabular}}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\small\thepage}
\addtolength\headheight{1pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\let\normal@seccntformat\@seccntformat
\newcommand\boxed@seccntformat{%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\colorbox{LightGrey}{%
  \hspace{-\fboxsep}\makebox[\linewidth][l]{%
    \strut\hfill\trafficlight{\tlcolor}{10}}}}\normal@seccntformat}

\newcommand\mysubsection[2]{%
\let\@seccntformat\boxed@seccntformat
\def\tlcolor{#2}%
\subsection[#1]{#1}%
\let\@seccntformat\normal@seccntformat
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
Yada yada.
\subsection{Normal subsection}
Yada yada.
\mysubsection{My subsection}{Green}
Yada yada.
\newpage
\mysubsection{This is not at the top of the page}{Red}
Yada yada.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Yes, that looks like the right thing. It works and you made my day.